# How to set up a global CSS for an entire page in Liferay DXP?

Tags: liferay

I am new to Liferay, and I still don't know the difference between the various 'kind' of Liferays.
This Liferay is what I am talking about.
[image]

I understand that you have to create a page first, and then add components (fragments) in it.
I also understand that you can go to `fragments`, and create a custom fragment with a custom CSS, and then import it into your page.
However, what I want to do is have a global CSS that I can use for all fragments inside a page, rather than having to add CSS for each `fragment`.
Is that possible, and if so, how?

I know I can use the 'style-books' which apply to an entire page, however, I don't know how to customize them, and it doesn't seem that that's even possible.

Comment: You could write a custom theme so that your stylesheets are part of version control repository. You can extend the liferay themes

Comment: How do I write a `custom theme`? Like I said, I am new to Liferay.

Comment: From Liferay documentation: "WARNING! Adding customizations to your site through a theme can come with increased maintenance when upgrading from one version of Liferay to another. When possible, manage your site’s appearance through the use of Master Pages Templates and Style Books" https://learn.lxc.liferay.com/w/dxp/site-building/site-appearance/themes/introduction-to-themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid coding, you can use the css additional textbox provide by theme settings.

It's a whole page css addon for every pages in the site

[image: theme css custom]

Comment: Thanks. I did that, and the classes applied, but now can't edit the css of each individual fragment inside the page? Why is that? I want to be able to have the classes defined in this 'theme', and then for each fragment, to add specific classes. Is that not possible? Also, how do I make bootstrap work in a page?